# Adding icon font on active state of bootstrap tabs

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Ok so I am trying to add an icon font (ionicons, just an arrow pointing up) below an active bootstrap tab, should be pretty simple but I cant figure it out!

I have this for my active state:

```
.services .nav > li.active > a .services-icon-holder {
background-color: #272727;
cursor: pointer;
}

.services .nav > li.active > a .services-icon {
color: #fff;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

Here is the effect I am trying to achieve:

[image: Active tab example]

You can check out [what I have here](http://aliensix.com/lightningbolt) (go to services section)

Comment: you can add like 'li.active:after {
    content: "∧";
}'

Comment: Awesome thats perfect! But do you have any idea how I can use an iconfont instead of the default "^"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can also define the font icon as well like this. I am assuming you are using `FontAwesome` for icons. you can find all icons list [here](http://astronautweb.co/snippet/font-awesome/).

```
li.active:after { 
    /*content: "∧"; */
    content: "\f106";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: inherit;
}
```