# Adding line below navigation link bootstrap scrollspy

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, scrollspy

I'm messing around with bootstrap scroll spy and I cant figure out how to a line below the link of the current section you are in.

Should be pretty simple but I cant get it! I want it to look like this:

[image]

So you are in the portfolio section and in turn portfolio would be highlighted WITH the stupid little line below. Can any one help out? You can check [live version here](http://aliensix.com/lightningbolt/) if needed.

Comment: You asked the same question with http://stackoverflow.com/q/22473580 , just use 'icon-minus'

Comment: so would i just target the navigation in this case as well? its a little different in this cause though

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22473793/2454790 says about li. Your scrollspy in ul-li too

Comment: Ok I almost got it I'm just having trouble centering it, do you mind taking a look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Customized class :

```
.navbar .nav li.active:after {
   content: "\f1ac";
   font-family: Ionicons;
   font-style: normal;
   font-size: 42px;
   color: #fff;
   position: absolute;   // <---- Add this 3 lines to center icon
   width: 100%;
   text-align: center;
}
```